# I'm trying to use require to access a local file, but if I use a variable in the path it doesn't work

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
import { Audio } from "expo-av";

const soundObject = new Audio.Sound();

export async function playSound(soundName) {
await soundObject.unloadAsync();
  try {
    await soundObject.loadAsync(require("../../assets/" + soundName + ".mp3")); //This does not
    await soundObject.loadAsync(require("../../assets/bark.mp3")); //This works
    await soundObject.playAsync();
    // Your sound is playing!
  } catch (error) {
    // An error occurred!
    await soundObject.playAsync();
  }
}
```

The question is about the first two statements in the try block. I indicate which works and which doesn't. I'm confused as to why string concatenation doesn't work in this context. Does it have something to with require?

Comment: you could try using fs module to "get" the file constructed both ways as you show with your 2 strings.. it just leaves behind the sound stuff and focuses on getting a file ref both ways

Comment: What is the error you're getting when it catches? It really is impossible that the behavior is different if it's truly the exact same string value being passed in for both cases. Is this something you're running through Webpack or babel perhaps? It would be instructive if you're using babel to see what the transpiled code looks like.

Comment: @Jacob I'm using react native and today I found that the code above works fine on the web build, but gives me this error on iOS or Android: Invalid call at line 6: require("../../assets/" + soundName + ".mp3")

Comment: Apparently the problem is that with the require module packaging happens once before runtime so the variable soundName would not have a value yet. Seems like I'll have to write a switch statement to get all the files instead of this dynamic way.